# Tensorflow python not loading the pre-trained model

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am getting the following error, while trying to run the decode mode for the trained model shared by the author of the [repository](https://github.com/abisee/pointer-generator).

```
python run_summarization.py --mode=decode  --data_path=better.bin --vocab_path=finished_files/vocab --log_root=log/directory --exp_name=pretrained_model
INFO:tensorflow:Starting seq2seq_attention in decode mode...
max_size of vocab was specified as 50000; we now have 50000 words. Stopping reading.
Finished constructing vocabulary of 50000 total words. Last word added: chaudhary
INFO:tensorflow:Building graph...
INFO:tensorflow:Adding attention_decoder timestep 0 of 1
INFO:tensorflow:Time to build graph: 0 seconds
2017-08-17 10:32:13.481390: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 10:32:13.481413: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 10:32:13.481429: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 10:32:13.481435: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 10:32:13.481440: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
INFO:tensorflow:Loading checkpoint log/directory/pretrained_model/train/model-238410
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from log/directory/pretrained_model/train/model-238410
2017-08-17 10:32:13.526779: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:13.527149: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:13.529141: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:13.531495: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:13.531495: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:13.533088: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
INFO:tensorflow:Failed to load checkpoint from log/directory/pretrained_model/train. Sleeping for 10 secs...
INFO:tensorflow:Loading checkpoint log/directory/pretrained_model/train/model-238410
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from log/directory/pretrained_model/train/model-238410
2017-08-17 10:32:23.631564: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:23.636247: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:23.638560: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:23.641101: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/bw/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:23.641189: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-08-17 10:32:23.642738: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key seq2seq/encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
INFO:tensorflow:Failed to load checkpoint from log/directory/pretrained_model/train. Sleeping for 10 secs...
```

Please let me know if there is any suggestion.

Comment: as per the code you have linked, have you trained your model `python run_summarization.py --mode=train --data_path=/path/to/chunked/train_* --vocab_path=/path/to/vocab --log_root=/path/to/a/log/directory --exp_name=myexperiment` or downloaded the pre trained model??

Comment: I have downloaded the pretrained model and also I have trained model on my system. But on my request, the author has provided the pre-trained model for checking the repository. Hence, was trying to run the model.'

Comment: based on the log I think your checkpoints are missing datapoint `seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint`. Check the code which saves checkpoint and make sure save weights is enable for all features.

Comment: @VikashSingh I didn't understood what this `seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/bias` I tried searching for it in my previous model it was not available and my model was working fine.

Comment: did you run `eval` also as `restore_best_model` code uses eval checkpoint.

Comment: I tried.. got the same error. Hence, I thought I should ask some help here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more than this :(

Comment: Thank you anyways my friend.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should have the same environments，python, tensorflow